# "all night last night" vs "all last night"

Tags: phrase-meaning

I have the following sentence in my grammar book:

> You studied **all night last night**, so tonight you ...

As I know we can say just **"all last night"**.

What's the need to add "night" in that phrase to get "all night last night"? Does it has some different meaning?

Comment: There might be some subtle nuance difference that I can't think of right now, but I believe they're the same. "All night last night" happens to be more idiomatic than "all last night"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a difference. "All last night" is possibly a slightly more colloquial version and almost sounds like a shortened form of "all night last night." The same phenomenon occurs with "all week last week" -> "all last week."

Can you say "I studied all yesterday" instead of "all day yesterday"? I think the answer is yes, but it begins to sound slightly more awkward/more colloquial to me.